# MFCActiveX can't run program with run error

Tags: mfc, activex

I created MFCActiveX Project in Visual Studio 2013 Pro, but I can't run this code (default) with this message:

```
C:\Users\JuneTaek\Desktop\MFC ActiveX control(MFCActiveX)\C++\Release\MFCActiveX.dll' can't start this program   can't find designated file )
```

Comment: Not able to understand your question.

Answer (score 2):

A DLL can not run without a process (EXE). So you need a hosting EXE. That is an EXE file that loads the DLL.

So you can use the Test Container, or the designated EXE where you want to use the ActiveX control.

Under the **Project Settings -> Configuration Properties -> Debugging -> Command** define the executable that should be launched in the debug session.  This executable should later load the ActiveX control you want to debug.